# Mongoid does not override existing documents through .create

Tags: ruby, mongodb, transactions, mongoid

I have the following class:

```
class Magazine
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :count
  field :_id, default: -> { name }
```

I create new documents of this type through `Magazine.create!(name: "Yolo", count: 2)`. This works fine. Now, when I want to update this document in MongoDB, because the count has changed, I thought this would work:

```
Magazine.create!(name: "Yolo", count: 42)
```

The name maps to the same identifier and so the document gets overriden. While it seems the operation was successful, in MongoDB the document was not updated.

Instead I have to do:

```
Magazine.where(name: "Yolo").first.update_attributes!(count: 42)
```

Which works, but can someone explain why my first approach does not work and if my second approach is the common way to update documents through Mongoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was reproduced on my machine and I found the solution.

`Model#create!` raises an error if a *validation error* occurs, not the *database error*, according to the [document](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#standard) or [the code on github](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb#L180). So it's not the solution to your question.

The [*Runtime Persistence Option*](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#custom) `with(safe: true)` could tell Mongoid to raise database errors defined in [the driver Moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html#errors). In your case. The error looks like:

```
1.9.3-p0 :009 > Magazine.with(safe: true).create!(name: "Yolo", count: 42)
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=71
  @request_id=7
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="mongoid.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :safe=>true}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 11000: "E11000 duplicate key error index: mongoid.magazines.$_id_  dup key: { : \"Yolo\" }"
```

Moreover, *safe mode* could be set as default in the config YAML, as described in the [document](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#safe_mode).

Perhaps you'd like to find a magazine with `Magazine.find("Yolo")` to use the index of `_id` created by MongoDB by default. Even if `_id` is the same with `name`, Mongoid is not smart enough to use `_id` to find the document.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm kind of surprised your second call to create! doesn't raise an error.

Try using the find method coupled with update, which is a pretty common one-liner for updating attributes:

```
Magazine.find('Yolo').update_attributes(count: 42)
```

Comment: `find` takes an ID as parameter, you probably mean `find_by(name: 'Yolo')`.

Comment: I know. 'Yolo' is the id, as well as the name.